# Page break print multiple pages vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a data set in sheet1 A1:L110, and I am trying to print it in two pages (each page 55 rows). But with the following code it is not showing the column L. Is there any suggestion to overcome the problem. Thank you.

```
`Sub PrintPage()
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 80
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$110"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(55).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L110").PrintOut Copies:=1, Preview:=True, ActivePrinter:=" ", Collate:=True

End Sub`
```

Comment: you use `ActiveSheet` - which may not be `Sheet1`. Replace `ActiveSheet` with `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and see what happens. Also try adding this line `Worksheets("Sheet1").VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1` before the `PrintOut` line.

Comment: @ Scott, It is giving the same output. also error at the VpageBreak..line

Comment: @ Scott I added following  then it works well.  '.Zoom = False                                                                                                        
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With following modification, I got the desired output. Thank you all.

```
`Sub PrintPage()
'Worksheets("Sheet1").ActivateActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
 Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Zoom = 80
 Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$110"
 With Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
 End With
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(55).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L110").PrintOut Copies:=1, Preview:=True,    ActivePrinter:=" ", Collate:=True
```

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I want also little bit help here.
I have a modified Sale Invoice so I want to page brake like after 13 rows and go next page for print without delete anything below of rows 13.
If I use built-in page break option then everything go on next page and i got white 30% white page from below.

Like this next page formula without delete anything from this point.

<#if(<#items.#RowCount> = 0;<#delete row>;)>

I want next page instead of delete row if empty or no.

If row is not empty then go next page.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to the OP's question.  If you have a question then please post your own question.  Don't tack on to someone else question